# What does it mean to categorify something?

Tags: category-theory, definition

What does it mean to categorify something?
Is there any simple illustrative example of this process?
How it is done and what is it useful for?

Here is where I heard it first: "[Khovanov homology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khovanov_homology) is the categorification of the [Jones polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jones_polynomial)." What's the meaning of this? What does categorification mean in general?

Comment: Actually I never met this expression. Intuitively I must think of creating a category that somehow 'catches' the mathematical theory that you are dealing with.

Comment: Here is where I heard it first, Khovanov homology is the categorification of the Jones polynomial. Whats the meaning of this?

Comment: Start by reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorification and, especially, references given there. This will keep you busy for a few days/weeks. If things are still unclear, ask a more focused question.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4841/what-precisely-is-categorification, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43579/examples-of-categorification